# Does the sum of the power of the smallest prime factor grow linearly?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, prime-factorization

Let $f(p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k})=a_1$ where $p_1<...<p_k$ and let $g(n)=\sum_{k<=n}f(k)$. Then is $g(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$?

I know that for $f(p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k})=k$ we would have gotten $g(n)=\Theta(n\log\log n)$, which follows from the fact that $\sum_{p<=n}\frac1p=\Theta(\log\log n)$ where $p$ must be prime. However, I intuitively expect $f(p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k})=a_1$ to be smaller on average.

If you're able to, I would also love to know if $g(n)/n$ converges to any specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(n) = \sup_{p^e | n} e$. Any integer decomposes uniquely as $nm^2$ with $n$ square-free. Also $h(m) \le 2\log m$ thus

$$\sum_{n \le x} f(n) \le \sum_{n \le x} h(n)=  \sum_{m \le x^{1/2}} \sum_{n \le x/m^2, |\mu(n)|=1} h(m^2 n)$$ $$ \le \sum_{n \le x} |\mu(n)| + \sum_{2 \le m \le x^{1/2}} (2 h(m)+1)\sum_{n \le x/m^2} |\mu(n)| \le   x(1+ \sum_{2 \le m \le x^{1/2}} \frac{4\log(m)+1}{m^2})$$ $$ \le  x(1+\zeta(2)-4\zeta'(2))$$

For a similar reason $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n \le x}f(n)}{x}$ converges to a non-zero value $\in [\frac{1}{\zeta(2)},1+\zeta(2)-4\zeta'(2)]$.

Comment: I think I understand the point and I like the square-free decomposition, but the details are confusing to me. So for $c=(\log2)^{-1}\approx1.44$ we have $h(m)\leq c\log m$. We also have $h(m^2n)\leq 2h(m)+h(n)=2h(m)+1$. Then $$\sum_{n\leq x}h(n)=\sum_{m\leq x^{1/2}}\sum_{n\leq x/m^2}|\mu(n)|h(m^2n)\leq\sum_{m\leq x^{1/2}}(2h(m)+1)\sum_{n\leq x/m^2}|\mu(n)|\leq x\sum_{m\leq x^{1/2}}\frac{2c\log m+1}{m^2}.$$ This is the idea right?

Comment: sure plus that $h(m^2n)=2h(m)$ when $|\mu(n)|=1$

Comment: {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: But for $n=m=2$ we have $h(m^2n)=3\neq 2=2h(m)$ and $|\mu(n)|=1$?

Comment: hmm right I need to replace $4$ by $6$ tks

Comment: this is a nice solution though, +1

Comment: @SmileyCraft I would appreciate if you could help me get my solution to work, since it would give limit value. Unfortunately, I don't know where the flaw is as of now.

Comment: @mathworker21 I will certainly look at it. But for now, this approach gives an upper bound. For $c=(\log2)^{-1}$ and $\xi=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\log m}{m^2}\approx0.94$ we have $\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\leq(2c\xi+\pi^2/6)x\leq5x$. See also https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+log(n)%2Fn%5E2+from+2+to+infinity for the value of $\xi$.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem**

Let $u(n)$ be the largest prime factor of $n$. The following is a proof that $$S:=\sum_{x\geq2}\frac{-\mu(x)}{x(u(x)-1)}$$ converges, and $g(n)/n\to S+1$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Basic manipulations**

Consider $\widehat{f}(n):=f(n)-1$ and $\widehat{g}(n):=\sum_{2\leq k\leq n}\widehat{f}(k)=g(n)-n+1$. We do some basic manipulations on $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$. By inclusion-exclusion, for any number $n$ with a prime factor $p$ we have $$\sum_{\substack{p_1<...<p_k<p\\p_1...p_k|n}}(-1)^k=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{if $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$}\\0&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Let $v_p(n)$ be the $p$-adic valuation of $n$, so the largest $k$ such that $p^k|n$. We get $$\widehat{g}(n)=\sum_{x=2}^n\sum_{p|x}\left(v_p(x)-1\right)\sum_{\substack{p_1<...<p_k<p\\p_1...p_k|x}}(-1)^k.$$ Using $v_p(x)-1=\sum_a1$ for $a\geq2$ with $p^a|x$, we get $$\widehat{g}(n)=\sum_{p_1<...<p_k<p}(-1)^k\sum_{a\geq2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p_1...p_kp^a}\right\rfloor.$$ Substituting $x=p_1...p_kp$ and $b=a-1$ we get $$\widehat{g}(n)=\sum_{x\geq2}-\mu(x)\sum_{b\geq1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{xu(x)^b}\right\rfloor.$$ So finally we can write $$\frac{\widehat{g}(n)}n=\sum_{x\geq2}\sum_{b\geq1}\frac{-\mu(x)}n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{xu(x)^b}\right\rfloor.$$ We can now move on to investigating the limiting behaviour.

**Infinite series**

This gives us motivation to look at the infinite series $$S=\sum_{x\geq2}\sum_{b\geq1}\frac{-\mu(x)}{xu(x)^b}.$$ Note that the sum over $b$ is a geometric series, so we can rewrite $$S=\sum_{x\geq2}\frac{-\mu(x)}{x(u(x)-1)}.$$ We show that the series is absolutely convergent, i.e., that the series $$\widehat{S}:=\sum_{x\geq2}\frac{|\mu(x)|}{x\left(u(x)-1\right)}$$ converges. We substitute $p=u(x)$ and sum over the primes $p$ first and then all $x\geq2$ with $|\mu(x)|=1$ and $u(x)=p$. We get $$\widehat{S}=\sum_p\frac1{p-1}\sum_{p_1<...p_k<p}\frac1{p_1...p_kp}.$$ With the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we can rewrite this as $$\widehat{S}=\sum_p\frac1{p(p-1)}\prod_{q<p}\left(1+q^{-1}\right).$$ Using $1+x\leq e^x$ we get $$\widehat{S}\leq\sum_p\frac1{p(p-1)}\exp\left(\sum_{q<p}\frac1q\right).$$ Since $\sum_{q<p}q^{-1}-\log\log p$ converges, we can bound $\sum_{q<p}q^{-1}\leq\log\log p+C$ for some constant $C$ to get $$\widehat{S}\leq e^C\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p(p-1)}.$$ That this series converges, even when summing over all positive integers $p$ instead of only the primes, can be seen with an integral test.

**Conclusion**

We view $\widehat{g}(n)/n$ as an infinite series. Every term converges to the corresponding term in $S$, while they are also absolutely bounded by the absolute value of that term in $S$. Since $S$ is absolutely convergent, we can conclude from this that $\widehat{g}(n)/n\to S$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $g(n)=\widehat{g}(n)+n-1$, it follows that $g(n)/n\to S+1$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Remarks**

Using the same techniques as with $\widehat{S}$ and the fact that $S$ converges absolutely, we can rewrite $$S=\sum_p\frac1{p(p-1)}\prod_{q<p}\left(1-q^{-1}\right).$$ This appears to make the series converge faster. Calculating the sum over the primes $p\leq10^8$ gives $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n)}n\approx1.6125177915.$$ I can also calculate the sum over the primes $p\leq10^{10}$ pretty fast. The aforementioned digits stay the same, but the double-precision floating-point format is not precise enough to give many more digits. Worth mentioning is that calculating the actual value $g(n)/n$ for large $n$ indeed seems to approach this value.

Comment: Just finished reading. Very nice! (and pleasant to read). There was one $n$ that should have been an $x$ that I fixed. The final form $\sum_p \frac{1}{p(p-1)}\prod_{q < p} (1-q^{-1})$ is indeed very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By inclusion-exclusion, $$\sum_{k \le n} f(k) = \sum_{\substack{p_1 < \dots < p_r \\ p_1\dots p_r \le n}} (-1)^{r+1}\sum_{\substack{k \le n \\ p_1\dots p_r | k}} v_{p_r(k)} = \sum_{\substack{p_1 < \dots < p_r \\ p_1\dots p_r \le n}} (-1)^{r+1} \sum_{j=1}^{n/(p_1\dots p_r)} \sum_{a \ge 1} 1_{p_r^a \mid p_1\dots p_r j} = \sum_{\substack{p_1 < \dots < p_r \\ p_1\dots p_r \le n}} (-1)^{r+1} \sum_{a \ge 1} \sum_{j=1}^{n/(p_1\dots p_r)} 1_{p_r^{a-1} \mid j} = \sum_{\substack{p_1 < \dots < p_r \\ p_1\dots p_r \le n}} (-1)^{r+1} \sum_{a \ge 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{p_1\dots p_{r-1} p_r^a} \rfloor.$$

Comment: I don't follow your first formula. You want to count $\sum_{k \le n, f(k) = m} 1$ right ? It is $\sum_{p \le n} \sum_{ n\le k/p^m, \gcd(n,\prod_{q \le p} q)=1} 1 = \sum_{p \le n} \sum_{d | \prod_{q \le p} q} \mu(d) \lfloor \frac{k/p^m}{d} \rfloor$

Comment: We sum $v_2(k)$ over even $k \le n$. We then sum $v_3(k)$ over $3 \mid k \le n$, but we have to subtract the sum of $v_3(k)$ over $6 \mid k \le n$. Etc.

Comment: What is $v_a(b)$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft maximum power of $a$ dividing $b$, i.e. $\sum_{j \ge 1} 1_{a^j \mid b}$. It is quite standard.

Comment: @SmileyCraft everything in the solution is correct now (I'm pretty sure). I just have to finish the asymptotics.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your fourth equality, it should be $p_r^a$ in the denominator. Because $j\leq n/(p_1...p_r)$ and $j$ is a multiple of $p_r^{a-1}$, so there are $\lfloor n/(p_1...p_r)/p_r^{a-1}\rfloor$ such $j$. I haven't read the rest yet.

Comment: @SmileyCraft thanks!

Comment: @SmileyCraft I'm not sure we can just get rid of the floor function, i.e. idk if we can just do $\lfloor x \rfloor \approx x$. I'll think more if you care about the exact value of the limit. If you're satisfied with Reuns's bounds, I'll stop.

Comment: Well we now have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}f(k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{\substack{p_1<...<p_r\\x=p_1...p_r\leq n}}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{a\geq1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{xp_r^{a-1}}\right\rfloor.$$ Let me substitute $b=a-1$ for convenience. The following step is the most controversial. $$=\sum_{\substack{p_1<...<p_r\\x=p_1...p_r}}(-1)^{r+1}\sum_{b\geq0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{xp_r^b}\right\rfloor.$$ I am not sure this is allowed here. But with this we get $$=\sum_{\substack{p_1<...<p_r\\x=p_1...p_r}}\frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{x}\frac{p_r}{p_r-1}.$$

Comment: So if we can show that we can swap the limit with the sums, which sounds very plausible to me, and if we can show the final sum converges, then we are done. It only remains to get an estimate for the final sum

Comment: @SmileyCraft it doesn't sound plausible to me, but I'll think more if there is anything I can do.

Comment: I just checked for $x$ up to $10^7$ and the sum is $1.6124175$. When I calculate $\frac1n\sum_{k\leq n}f(k)$ for $n=10^7$ I get $1.6125084$. So to me it seems like we have a winner. Somewhat ironically, though, this sum seems to converge at a slower rate than the original sum.

Comment: @SmileyCraft oh, awesome! thanks for letting me know. I always am surprised when theory turns out to work. I trust computers more than proofs. Well, I guess in this case, we didn't have the theory proven. And to clarify, I meant that I find it very implausible that we can easily prove the interchange of limits is allowed, not that it is.

Comment: @mathworker21 I managed to rigorously prove the result and find a faster method of calculating the limit, see my newly added answer :)

Comment: @SmileyCraft Hey!! I took a bit of a break from MSE; I just saw this now. I hope all is well :)